# Create a simple MatLab command to create a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am incredibly new to MatLab (I only started looking at it today). I'm trying to do some sample questions and I'm stuck on this one. I;m sure it's very easy. The Q is: Write a Matlab command to create the following matrix (sArray), followed by the command to graph the 3rd row of the matrix. The grid of the graph should be set to visible and the x ('test') and y ('value') axis labels should be included. 
[image: matrix]

No doubt this will take someone less than 30 seconds to do.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the 3rd row of the matrix are the Y values for your graph, what are the X values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [16 456 22 85 93; 11 78 310 62 36; 1 66 23 67 405]

figure
plot(A(3,:))
xlabel('test')
ylabel('value')
```

I suggest to take a look at [this](http://www.math.utah.edu/~eyre/computing/matlab-intro/matrices.html)